# Sending large files from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows-xp, ftp

I have been trying to send a large backup file (over 2G) from debian Linux to a Windows XP machine. I've had problems using CIFS, e.g.:

```
Jan 16 11:39:58 debian kernel: [3205845.238084] CIFS VFS: Server server has not responded in 300 seconds. Reconnecting...
Jan 16 11:46:30 debian kernel: [3206237.958071] CIFS VFS: Server server has not responded in 300 seconds. Reconnecting...
Jan 16 11:49:14 debian kernel: [3206402.019072] CIFS VFS: No task to wake, unknown frame received! NumMids 0
Jan 16 11:49:14 debian kernel: [3206402.021454] Received Data is: : dump of 37 bytes of data at 0xf6f21e40
Jan 16 11:49:14 debian kernel: [3206402.021466]  23000000 424d53ff 5b0002a4 80018000 . . . # ÿ S M B ¤ . . [ . . . .
Jan 16 11:49:14 debian kernel: [3206402.021477]  00000000 00000000 00000000 25860000 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . %
Jan 16 11:49:14 debian kernel: [3206402.021483]  6f740000 03000000 . . t o .
```

I have tried activating the IIS FTP server on my XP machine. I'm using the following to transfer the file:

```
pftp -n <<EOF
open server
user anonymous nobody@myserver.net.au
binary
put $BACKFILE
EOF
```

This works sometimes, but when I run this as a cron job I sometimes get messages like this:

```
netout: Broken pipe
```

and

```
netout: Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried splitting the file into 1GB blocks, but this makes restoring files difficult and I still get occasional errors when I use CIFS. Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Any possibility of getting SSH running on the Windows machine? Then you could use SCP.

Answer (score 0):

[Bittorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) might work for you, if you have no hard time requirements. Easy to install and it works nicely.

Comment: I didn't point out on my original post that I only need to send the files within my local network.  Bittorrent seems like overkill to me.  Is it a know issue that large files cause problems when sent over a network from Linux to Windows using FTP and CIFS?  Can anybody explain what the above error messages mean?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a torrent of your file(s) or using Bittorrent Sync as mention by nwahmaet is probably your best bet, it might take some time, but you dont have to worry about connection errors, the torrent will just resume where it was when you start it up again, also torrent-clients(at least most) perform hashing on the data to verify its integrity.

What you'll need if you wanna create your own torrent is a static ip for the duration of the transfer, an open port in your router, uTorrent(works on both [xp](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/win) and [debian](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux)) or similar program (you need one that can function as both client and tracker, which utorrent can).

Detailed instructions can be found here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33597/bittorrent-for-beginners-share-large-files-using-your-own-private-tracker/

and here:

http://bootstrike.com/Articles/CreateTorrent/

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer - our complete network stopped functioning a few days ago and was fixed by powering our network hub/switch off and on.  I've replaced it and things seem to be working OK now.

As I suspected for a while - this seems to be a hardware problem.